# hash-tables, counting duplicate keys, scheme

Tags: hash, scheme

I'm hoping someone can help me with this while I continue searching for a solution.

I'm confused on how to iterate through a hash table and find duplicate keys. I want to remove the duplicates, but consolidate their values.

So, say I have a list of strings:

```
(define strings '("abcde" "bcdea" "cdeab" "deabc" "eabcd" "abcde"))
```

And I store them into a hash table where the values are their index positions in the list.

So, I'm wanting to build a hash table like this:

```
(abcde (0, 5))
(bcdea 1)
(cdeab 2)
(deabc 3)
(eabcd 4)
```

Each string is a key, and the value is a list of the indexes where that string is found. Basically, I'm counting the number of occurrences of a substring in a large string, and noting their positions.

I know how to make the hash table:

```
(define my-hash-table (make-hash))
  (for-each (lambda (s v) (hash-set! my-hash-table s v)) strings values)  ;;values is a list of 0,1,2,3,4,5
  (map (lambda (s) (list s (hash-ref my-hash-table s))) strings)
```

This just builds a hash table of the keys and their values, it doesn't consider if a key is already present in the table.

I'd appreciate any advice. If someone doesn't mind going through it step-by-step with me I'd be very grateful, I'm trying to learn scheme.

I'm using RSR5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to check whether each key has already a value, if so we append it to a list - by definition, each key can only have *one* value associated. I think you're looking for something like this:

```
(define strings '("abcde" "bcdea" "cdeab" "deabc" "eabcd" "abcde"))
(define values  '(0 1 2 3 4 5))

(define my-hash-table (make-hash))
(for-each (lambda (s v)
            (hash-update! my-hash-table
                          s
                          (lambda (a) (cons v a)) ; add element to list
                          (lambda () '())))       ; we start with '()
          strings
          values)
```

Alternatively, we can create and update the hash table using a functional style of programming:

```
(define my-hash-table
  (foldl (lambda (s v a)
           (hash-update a
                        s
                        (lambda (a) (cons v a)) ; add element to list
                        (lambda () '())))       ; we start with '()
         (hash)
         strings
         values))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(hash->list my-hash-table) ; we get a keys/values list for free
=> '(("eabcd" 4) ("deabc" 3) ("bcdea" 1) ("cdeab" 2) ("abcde" 5 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [SRFI 69](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-69/srfi-69.html)? Look into `hash-table-update!`.